# Multiprocessing Pool method hanging but Process method working

Tags: windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to get the `multiprocessing.Pool` method to work. It initiates and shows all the cores are active, although ends up just stalled without completing.

To troubleshoot the problem, I first tried using a simple `for` loop and that worked (Method 1 below). I also tried using the `multiprocessing.Process` method, which also worked (Method 2 below).

Method 3 (below), however, just hangs. Where might I be going wrong in implementing the `multiprocessing.Pool` method?

---

```
import arcpy, os, glob, multiprocessing

# Method 1 works
inws = r'C:\temp\raster_data'
rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))

def worker(raster):
    arcpy.arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(raster)
    arcpy.AddField_management(raster, "Cover", "TEXT", "", "", 20)

for raster in rasters:
    worker(raster)

# Method 2 works
def mp_worker(raster):
    arcpy.arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(raster)
    arcpy.AddField_management(raster, "Cover", "TEXT", "", "", 20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inws = r'C:\temp\raster_data'
    rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))
    for raster in rasters:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mp_worker(raster))
        p.start()
        p.join()

# Method 3 not working
def mp_worker(raster):
    arcpy.arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(raster)
    arcpy.AddField_management(raster, "Cover", "TEXT", "", "", 20)

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    p.map(mp_worker, rasters)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inws = r'C:\temp\raster_data'
    rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))
    mp_handler()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if its relevant to the issue you're having, but your "Method 2" code won't do any parallel processing, since you are `join`ing each process before starting up the next one. For it to run in parallel, you'd need to do the `join` calls in a separate loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mp_worker(raster))
```

should probably be like this

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mp_worker, args=(raster,))
```

Otherwise you are calling the function `mp_worker` when there should be a reference to it.